# Calling sourceCodeAt on a String variable x='X'. How to change it to X?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to go through all the methods is a specific class using the block

```
an_object class methods do: [:n | ....]
```

in order to get their parameters automatically.
I need to call `sourceCodeAt` for a method. But I have this method in a variable as String. Instead of X I have 'X'. How can I change it to X ,as a method instance, to be able to call sourceCodeAt on it?

Comment: and honestly I don't understand what's up with X. Maybe you can proved some examples?

Comment: I use the following: an_object class methods do: [:n |
When I print n I get: LinkedList2>>#RemoveAnElement:. While, I need to get only the method name #RemoveAnElement. I pass the method name to the method:sourceCodeAt in order to get the parameters.  But i did not succeed!

Comment: I used this obj:=x asSymbol where x is the method name as a string, and it works! I am now trying to extract the methods' headers automatically. Is it better to get them from the source code by reading the first line of the method?

Comment: While it's very usual to put message pattern on first line (I mean keywords and arguments), this is not mandatory, and you could as well find some patterns split across several lines (a sign that they are too many), or some other code on the 1st line (very rare formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, look: `#methods` message sent to a class object (Behavior subclass) will return a collection of instances of `CompiledMetod`. I have no idea what do you mean by *get parameters* but (at least in Pharo3) you can send `#argumentNames` to a `CompiledMetod` in order to get names of arguments. Otherwise you can send `#selector` to get a symbol representing a selector (name) of a method. And of course when you print it, you get *Class>>method* because it's defined like that in a `#printOn:` method of `CompiledMetod` class.

If you want to get a source code for a method just ask a method for it. E.i:

```
an_object class methods do: [ :method | method sourceCode ....]
```

Comment: I use the following: an_object class methods do: [:n | When I print n I get: LinkedList2>>#RemoveAnElement:. While, I need to get only the method name #RemoveAnElement. I pass the method name to the method:sourceCodeAt in order to get the parameters. But i did not succeed because I could send just '#RemoveAnElement' not #RemoveAnElement.

Comment: @Asan I've expanded the answer

Comment: I used this obj:=x asSymbol where x is the method name as a string, and it works. I am now trying to extract the methods' headers automatically. Is it better to get them from the source code by reading the first line of the method?

Comment: @Asan as I've already written you can get a lot of data (like argument names) from a `CompiledMethod`. Also you can get an AST from it. Why do you want to work with string so much?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the source code in a string, you don't need the "sourceCodeAt:". Just use the string you have.  The sourceCodeAt: method fetches the source code for an existing method and returns a string.  If you already have the string containing the source code, just use it.